# Creating a related content block in Drupal 7 using OpenCalais

Tags: 7

How do I use [OpenCalais](http://drupal.org/project/opencalais) to display related content in Drupal 7?

I would think I have to create a view, or something. I have nearly all the OpenCalais categories enabled (I'm creating a site for a newspaper), so it seems somewhat impractical to use them all as filters. I think you're supposed to use the [More Like This](http://drupal.org/project/morelikethis) module, but it doesn't have a Drupal 7 release. I am genuinely confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Calais will take your content and through their web service create metadata for it which the opencalais module can use to create an amazingly diverse variety of taxonomy terms that are applied to your nodes. It is a really cool service.

Once your content had the tags added by OpenCalais you could use one of the modules that provide a "Similar Content" block: http://drupal.org/node/323329 . Most of them are based on taxonomy terms. The [More Like This](http://drupal.org/project/morelikethis) module doesn't look like it has a D7 release but looks like it also uses taxonomy terms.

The simplest method for making a "More Like This" block might be to use [Search API Solr](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) or [ApacheSolr](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr). If you have full access to your server it is [not that difficult](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/solr_ubuntu.html) to install. Solr's version of [More Like This](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis) uses Solr's search engine to determine similar content on your site. Also a very very cool technology.

Comment: That's tremendously helpful -- I've been thinking of installing Solr anyway to help with search (Also, should have mentioned I've already tagged all content via OpenCalais, am just needing some way to associating relevant articles with each other). Will give that a shot!

Comment: If you already have the content tagged by OpenCalais then it would probably be easiest to use one of the blocks that uses Taxonomy for a similar term block but Solr is a great thing to have at your disposal anyway. Would be interesting to see the differences in Solr's MLT vs a Similar Content module.

Comment: I used the dev version of [Related Links](http://drupal.org/project/relatedlinks) -- works well. Thanks!